# How to use HTTP response with custom authentication header

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, http, authentication, http-headers

What I am trying to do is send http response to browser with my custom http header. I expect browser to pass that custom http head back to web server every time it make request.
But it does not.

I am using C# ASP.net MVC.
When I return my custom ActionResult.

```
public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
{
            base.ExecuteResult(context);
            context.HttpContext.Response.AppendHeader("AuthenticationInfo", "1234567890");
}
```

Comment: which language are you using to develop it? have you tried anything?

Comment: Please mention code of passing header.How you are trying to pass header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I need to do is response HTTP header as a cookie.